# Android AVD Target is Unselectable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I've been stuck all day trying to Create a virtual device in android AVD. However, in the "Create" form the *Target* is greyed out and unable to be selected. Then at the end of the form I get an error for not selecting a target! What?!

[image]

Many answers to similar questions reference the older eclipse platform. I am using the Android Studio powered by Intellij version 2.1.3, and I'm on a mac with 10.11.5 osx.

I have also already installed many things from the Android SDK Manager:

[image]

At this point I'm not sure what else to do. Can anyone see how I could fix the issue? Thanks.

Comment: what is you build target version? hopefully one out of 17 or 24.

Comment: did you ever solve this ?